# PHP IF shorthand variations similar to ternary

Tags: php

Is there another way of writing something like this?

```
$var2 = ($var1) ? $var1 : 'bar';
```

Example..

```
$var1 = 'foo';
$var2 = ($var1) ? $var1 : 'bar';
echo $var2; //Outputs foo

$var1 = false;
$var2 = ($var1) ? $var1 : 'bar';
echo $var2; //Outputs bar
```

I hoped

```
$var2 = $var1 || 'bar';
```

would work because I thought I've seen that before but it didn't.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$var2 = $var1 ?: 'bar';
```

New since PHP 5.3. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct. Since PHP 5.3 (I believe) there is a new construct:

```
<?php
$foo = false;
$foo = $foo ?: 'bar';

echo $foo; // $foo is now "bar".
```

Answer (score -2):

There is not prior to PHP 5.3.

If compatability to pre-5.3 versions of PHP is important I suggest making a method;

```
function b($a, $b) { return $a?$a:$b; }
```

B for best, as well as being short.

Usage:

```
echo b($username, "Not logged in");
```